# How to use figures in an equation

Tags: equations

I have to write an equation(3) that should partially use figures(1)(2) (which display a decision tree).

Is this possible, or what other way would you suggest making this work?

(1)

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        sibling distance        = 10em,
        level distance          = 10em,
        edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
        every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
        sloped
    ]
        \node [root] {73.3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:desicion_tree_F0}
\end{figure}
```

(2)

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
            sibling distance        = 6em,
            level distance          = 3em,
            edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
            every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
            sloped
        ]
            \node [root] {Height < 2.3}
            child {
                node [env][label={[label distance=0.1em]270:$r_{3,1}$},label={[label distance=0em]180:$R_{1,1}$},label={[label distance=1em]270:$\gamma_{1,1} = -13.3$}] { $-13.3$ }
            }
            child {
                node [env][label={[label distance=0.1em]270:$r_{1,1}$, $r_{2,1}$},label={[label distance=0em]0:$R_{2,1}$}, label={[label distance=1em]270:$\gamma_{2,1} = 9.3$}] { $15.6$, $3.0$ }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Desicion Tree with Residuals calculated}
    \label{fig:desicion_tree_residuals}
\end{figure}
```

And I would need to write something like:
(3)

```
\begin{equation}
    F_{1} = \ref{fig:desicion_tree_F0} + \lambda * \ref{fig:desicion_tree_residuals}
\end{equation}
```

But instead of just referencing, it would be nice if it would actually display the trees inline with the equation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The primary purpose of a figure is to move to a different location.  You don't need them for graphics or even captions (`\captionof{figure}{...}`).

Comment: as john says just use tikzpicture directly in the math

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Should I add the solution to this question myself, or would you @JohnKormylo like to add it?